# JQuery Draggable On Portion of Table Row

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a table for which I would like to make the rows draggable with JQuery (users can select a row and drag the row to another element on my UI which drops the row's data into that element). I set each row ("tr" element) of the table to the class "draggableRow," and I have created the appropriate functionality for all this to work for elements of that class (e.g., setting a draggable function for that class).

However, I do not want the user to be able to drag from the first column (i.e., first "td" in the row). One option would be to make the "td" elements draggable, but because of padding issues, this does not feel as crisp. There are dead zones in the table row that are not draggable.

Thus, an alternative would be to keep the draggable on the "tr" but somehow figure out that the user clicked the first "td" in the row (e.g., by $(event.target).closest("td") in the helper function) and then stop the drag. However, I am not sure how to stop the drag.

Any help would be appreciated. The best would be to find some way to make the entire row except the first "td" draggable (including the padding between table cells). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Cancel' option seems to be what you're looking for: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel

> Prevents dragging from starting on specified elements.

```
  $('tr').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cancel: 'td:first-child'
    });
```

Edit: I made you an example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Emsxg/1/